# Scala Sorting with Another Json's Key

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Scala and please help me out.
I have 2 Json file. I want to sort first json with a key from the second json.

For eg:
First Json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "response" : [{
            "user_id" : 1,
            "products" : [
                {
                    "product_id": 10,
                    "price": 200
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 13,
                    "price": 210
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 9,
                    "price": 320
                }
            ] 
        },{
            "user_id" : 2,
            "products" : [
                {
                    "product_id": 15,
                    "price": 200
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 13,
                    "price": 210
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 8,
                    "price": 320
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And My Second Json

```
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "rank": 5
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "rank": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "rank": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "rank": 2
                },{
                    "id": 15,
                    "rank": 6
                },{
                    "id": 17,
                    "rank": 4
                },{
                    "id": 20,
                    "rank": 7
                },{
                    "id": 21,
                    "rank": 8
                },{
                    "id": 23,
                    "rank": 9
                }
            ]
        },{
            "user_id": 2,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "rank": 5
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "rank": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "rank": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "rank": 2
                },{
                    "id": 15,
                    "rank": 6
                },{
                    "id": 17,
                    "rank": 4
                },{
                    "id": 20,
                    "rank": 7
                },{
                    "id": 21,
                    "rank": 8
                },{
                    "id": 23,
                    "rank": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort my first json with respect to the rank I have in second Json.

Output should be like each user should have his products in sorted order based on the rank that is specified for each user on the second JSON.

This is so far what I have tried

```
def sortedRes() = Action.async {
    val url = //1st json url
    val sortUrl = //2nd json url
    ws.url(url).get().map { response =>
      val value: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
      val result: Either[Exception, SampleResponses] = value.validate[SampleResponses] match {
        case JsSuccess(searchResponse, _) =>
          Right(searchResponse)
        case JsError(errors) =>
          Left(new Exception("Couldn't parse Search API response"))
      }

      val values: List[SampleResponse] = result.right.get.responses

      ws.url(sortUrl).get().map { response =>
        val sorted: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)


        val sortRespResult: Either[Exception, Sort] = sorted.validate[Sort] match {
          case JsSuccess(sortResponse, _) =>
            Right(sortResponse)
          case JsError(errors) =>
            Left(new Exception("Couldn't parse because of these errors : " + errors))
        }

        val prodRankDetails: List[SampleRank] = sortRespResult.right.get.sort

        println("prod = " + prodRankDetails.head.products.sortWith(_.rank > _.rank))
      }
      Ok(Json.toJson(result.right.get))
    }
  }
```

In the last print statement I got the second json's first users product sorted. What I am trying to get is my first json sorted based on the second user.

Here is my model class

```
package models

import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json._ // Combinator syntax


object sample {
  case class SampleProduct(productId:Int, price: Int)
  case class SampleResponse(userId: Int, products: List[SampleProduct])
  case class SampleResponses(id: Int, responses: List[SampleResponse])
  case class SampleRankedProduct(id: Int, rank: Int)
  case class SampleRank(userId: Int, products: List[SampleRankedProduct])
  case class Sort(sort: List[SampleRank])

  implicit val productReads: Reads[SampleProduct] = (
    (JsPath \ "product_id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "price").read[Int]
    )(SampleProduct.apply _)

  implicit val productWrites: Writes[SampleProduct] = (
    (JsPath \ "product_id").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "price ").write[Int]
    )(unlift(SampleProduct.unapply))

  implicit val responseReads: Reads[SampleResponse] = (
    (JsPath \ "user_id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "products").read[List[SampleProduct]]
    )(SampleResponse.apply _)

  implicit val responseWrites: Writes[SampleResponse] = (
    (JsPath \ "user_id").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "products").write[List[SampleProduct]]
    )(unlift(SampleResponse.unapply))

  implicit val responsesReads: Reads[SampleResponses] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "response").read[List[SampleResponse]]
    )(SampleResponses.apply _)

  implicit val responsesWrites: Writes[SampleResponses] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "response").write[List[SampleResponse]]
    )(unlift(SampleResponses.unapply))

  implicit val rankedProductReads: Reads[SampleRankedProduct] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "rank").read[Int]
    )(SampleRankedProduct.apply _)

  implicit val rankedProductWrites: Writes[SampleRankedProduct] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "rank ").write[Int]
    )(unlift(SampleRankedProduct.unapply))

  implicit val rankReads: Reads[SampleRank] = (
    (JsPath \ "user_id").read[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "products").read[List[SampleRankedProduct]]
    )(SampleRank.apply _)

  implicit val rankWrites: Writes[SampleRank] = (
    (JsPath \ "user_id").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "products").write[List[SampleRankedProduct]]
    )(unlift(SampleRank.unapply))

  implicit val sortReads: Reads[Sort] = (JsPath \ "sort").read[List[SampleRank]].map(x ⇒ Sort(x))

  implicit val sortWrites: Writes[Sort] = (__ \ "sort").write[List[SampleRank]].contramap { (person: Sort) => person.sort }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried as code effort?

Comment: @cchantep I have updated what I have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach for sorting the first JSON using the ranking from the second one, is something like that:

```
....
val prodRankDetails: List[SampleRank] = sortRespResult.right.get.sort

val sortedResults = values.copy(
  responses = values.responses.map { resultForUser =>
    val rankingForUser = prodRankDetails
      .find(_.userId == resultForUser.userId)
      .getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Rank not found for user ${resultForUser.userId}"))
      .products
      .map(product => (product.id, product.rank))
      .toMap

    resultForUser.copy(
      products = resultForUser.products.sortWith((a, b) =>
        rankingForUser.getOrElse(a.productId, Int.MaxValue) < rankingForUser.getOrElse(b.productId, Int.MaxValue))
    )

  }
)
Ok(Json.toJson(sortedResults))
```

that should be performed just after you got `prodRankDetails`. And also the response will be available inside the `.map` as you are managing a `Future`.
So you have to move also the `Ok(...)` inside that map and to `flatMap` the outer `Future`.

Hope this helps.